# get the index of element I select using .filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I would like to get the index of an element I select using `.filter`. The code looks like this:

```js
abc = $('.abc').find('.el').clone();
log = abc.filter('.def');
```

I get the element but I need its index (like nth-child position within the cloned data in abc. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following variation of [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element):

> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element
> or jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer
> indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original
> collection.

```
var index = abc.index(log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp#:%7E:text=The%20indexOf()%20method%20searches,the%20item%20is%20not%20found.)

```js
let array = ['.a', '.de', '.def']
let index = array.indexOf('.def')
console.log(index) // 2

// if index > -1, it exists in the array

let array = ['.a', '.de']
let index = array.indexOf('.def')
console.log(index) // -1
```

Comment: `abc` would be a jQuery object, not an array